# What might cause a string in R to have a bad space character?

Tags: r, string, corruption

I've been working in R for a few months now, so I'm fairly new.  I'm not new to programming, though, and I have never seen this particular issue before.

I have some survey data, that I am parsing questions and answers out of.  One of my questions is "How engaged are you feeling?"

I had no problems with any other questions, but when I tried to `filter` (dplyr) on this questions, I kept getting zero matches.  Then I tried using `grepl` instead of `==`.  `grepl` worked on substrings of the questions, but not the whole question. Eventually, I narrowed it down to the space between "engaged" and "are" that seems to be the issue.

With the data subsetted and loaded into a variable called `newtest`, the results are as follows:

```
grepl("How engaged", newtest$question)

[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

But then:

```
grepl("engaged are", newtest$question)

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If I overwrite the question in the column with the same string, "How engaged are you feeling", everything works fine again.

This is fine for a short term fix, but this is coming out of a database, so I'm a little concerned of where this "bad space" might have come from, and whether there are more of them.  Even after writing out the csv and reading it back in, the problem persists.

Any thoughts on a cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `?clean` from `library(qdap)` might be an option.  `x1 <- c('engaged    are', 'engaged are', 'engaged  are', 'engaged   are'); grep('engaged are', clean(x1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks.  The strange thing is that I tried `grepl` using `\s`, `\s{2}`, `\t` in the pattern instead of just a "space," and it still didn't work.  Don't know what the escaped character is.

Comment: What if you use the `[:space:]` character class?